# How, Using MVVM, would I dynamically create a textbox with a bound value, only to destroy it after 5 seconds?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, createelement

So, I want to create a textbox at a certain location on my WPF application window, and I want to give it a certain value. Wil either be an integer converted to string, or a string. How would I create the textbox upon an event being triggered, and then destroy it 5 seconds later?

I need to be able to have multiple of these at the same time, so I may do the following:
Spawn 1 textbox with value X
wait 2 seconds
Spawn 1 textbox with value Y
wait 3 seconds
destroy first textbox
destroy second textbox

etc. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just create the textboxes in the xaml and then just toggle the visibility with the event triggers?

Comment: I dont know how many I will need. Sometimes, I will not have any visible, but other times I may have up to10 - 20 visible at a given time. Binding the values to "value1", "value2", and then deciding which one to use constantly would be quite a headache...

Comment: This whole requirement sounds like a headache quite honestly. This isn't really something in the realm of mvvm. You are going to have to probably do this all in code-behind so you can programatically create textboxes. You'll also probably will need to reference your viewmodel in your code-behind, via the DataContext, since I assume that will be where your data comes from.

Comment: Is there honestly no way to do this whilst sticking with MVVM? Code behind so far is setting the datacontext and thats all, that was the way I was aiming to keep it... :(

Comment: This is anti-mvvm. Think about it. ViewModels know NOTHING about the UI. So you can't do anything in your viewmodel to build textbox elements. Maybe you could use some attachedbehavior, but that's not really an MVVM specific concept. Also, doing things in code-behind isn't breaking mvvm. Sometimes UI specific things like this need to be done and the best place is in code-behind.

Comment: James' answer below should actually work well and be quick to implement. Forgot about ItemsControl.

Answer (score 2):

Use an Items control and specify item template as a textbox , then bind your data collection to the items control.

Here is a possible xaml for the items control:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TextBoxDataCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=. }" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

You can bind to a collection for example as below:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> TextBoxDataCollection { get; set; }
```

Now in your code if you want 3 text boxes then your collection should look like the one below:

```
TextBoxDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "", "", "" };
```

You can retrieve the data typed in the textbox using the same collection back.

Once you remove or add more strings into the collection it should create more text boxes for you.

If you are fancy enough you can have more complex objects other than strings in the collection.

Comment: Thanks. I'm unfamiliar with how I would go about doing this however, could you give a small code sample if possible please? :)

Comment: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/

There are good examples on here that will show you how to do an item control.

As far as the template goes, it would just be a normal DataTemplate that you would create with a TextBox that you would then set the ItemsControlTemplate property to.

Comment: <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TextBoxDataCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=. }" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

Comment: This is correct, yet it is incorrect.  Strings are immutable, so you can't change them.  And Bindings will **not** replace item X at index Y within a collection.  All the `TextBox` has is the string, which is immutable, and doesn't know where it exists within the collection, which is bound to a parent control.  What you ***need*** to do is wrap your string in a Model of some sort, expose that in your collection, then change the value of a string property on that model via a bound TextBox.

Comment: @MatthewParker this is what you need to do, but there's a bug in this answer.  See my above comment for clarification.  I'll give the director here an opportunity to fix rather than add my own answer.